# How to Turn a Car around to face the opposite direction on key press in PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

How to turn a car around to face the opposite direction on a key press in `PyGame`

I am making a game where a car will avoid an object on the road, and I want the car to be able to turn and face the opposite direction when I press a particular key (not just moving left, right, up, and down) but to be able to turn and around and face any particular position that I want it to face.

```
import turtle
import pygame
import os

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

BACKGROUND_WIDTH, BACKGROUND_HEIGHT = 900, 500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((BACKGROUND_WIDTH, BACKGROUND_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Avoid Obstacles")

ROAD_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(
 os.path.join("Assets", "road.png"))

CAR_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(
 os.path.join("Assets", "carone.png"))
VELOCITY = 3.2


class Cars:

   def __init__(self, x, y, car_width, car_height, car_image, turning):
     self.x = x
     self.y = y
     self.car_width = car_width
     self.car_height = car_height
     self.car_image = car_image
     self.turning = turning

     # handles the drawing and resizing of images
     def draw_window(self, car):
        pygame.transform.flip(CAR_IMAGE, True, False)

        CAR_ONE = pygame.transform.scale(
        self.car_image, (self.car_width, self.car_height))
        WIN.fill(WHITE)

        WIN.blit(pygame.transform.scale(
         ROAD_IMAGE, (BACKGROUND_WIDTH, BACKGROUND_HEIGHT)), (0, 0))
        WIN.blit(CAR_ONE, (car.x, car.y))
        pygame.display.update()

     # handles car movements when keys are pressed
     def handles_car_movement(self, keys_pressed, car):
        if(keys_pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]):  # Turn LEFT KEY
          car.x -= self.turning

        if(keys_pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]):  # Turn RIGHT KEY
          car.x += self.turning
        # handes the storing and manipulating of rectangular areas, proccessing and 
     function calls

     def main(self):
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        carWithPosition = pygame.Rect(
         self.x, self.y, self.car_width, self.car_height)

     run = True
     while run:
        clock.tick(60)
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            self.handles_car_movement(keys_pressed, carWithPosition)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
        self.draw_window(carWithPosition)
    pygame.quit()


cars = Cars(500, 300, 55, 40, CAR_IMAGE, 5)

if(__name__ == "__main__"):
  cars.main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pygame.transform.flip`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html) does not flip the image itselfe, but returns a new and flipped image. e.g.:

<s>`pygame.transform.flip(CAR_IMAGE, True, False)`</s>

```py
CAR_IMAGE = pygame.transform.flip(self.car_image, True, False)
```

Create 2 images for each care (e.g.: `slef.CAR_LEFT` and `self.CAR_RGIHT`) and assign the image for the first direction to the attribute `self.CAR_ONE`. Change the image when the button is pressed:

```py
class Cars:

    def __init__(self, x, y, car_width, car_height, car_image, turning):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.car_width = car_width
        self.car_height = car_height
        self.car_image = car_image

        self.CAR_RIGHT = pygame.transform.scale(self.car_image, (self.car_width,  self.car_height))
        self.CAR_LEFT = pygame.transform.flip(self.CAR_RIGHT, True, False)
        self.CAR_ONE = self.CAR_RIGHT
```

```py
    def draw_window(self, car):
        
        WIN.blit(pygame.transform.scale(ROAD_IMAGE, (BACKGROUND_WIDTH, BACKGROUND_HEIGHT)), (0, 0))
        WIN.blit(self.CAR_ONE, (car.x, car.y))
        pygame.display.update()

    def handles_car_movement(self, keys_pressed, car):
        if(keys_pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]):  # Turn LEFT KEY
            car.x -= self.turning
            car.CAR_ONE = car.CAR_LEFT

        if(keys_pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]):  # Turn RIGHT KEY
            car.x += self.turning    
            car.CAR_ONE = car.CAR_RIGHT
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than changing the x position when turning, try giving the car a rotation and moving it's position based off of that using Trig. such as:

```
def handles_car_movement(self, keys_pressed, car):
    if(keys_pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]):  # Turn LEFT KEY
      car.rotation -= self.turning 

    if(keys_pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]):  # Turn RIGHT KEY
      car.rotation += self.turning

  car.x += cos(car.rotation)
```

And also render the car with the proper rotation in your `draw_window`
(I believe something like:)

```
CAR_ONE = pygame.transform.rotate(self.car_image, self.rotation)
```

**Be sure to be consistent between Radians and Degrees**

Comment: The car has only 2 possible directions (left and right).  A pygame surface can be turned with `pygame.transform.flip`.